# Instead method for Priority.DEBUG in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I want to upgrade log4j 1.2 version to log4j 2.7 version with slf4j. in my code having.

```
if (logger.isEnabledFor(Priority.DEBUG)){
            logger.debug("Exit checkAccess()");
        }
```

this function but the Priority.DEBUG method is deprecated so instead of that i am using Level.DEBUG and import "org.slf4j.event.Level"  but still it shows following error "The method isEnabledFor(Level) is undefined for the type Logger"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution for this problam..

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled(){
        logger.debug("Exit checkAccess()");
    }
```

this is implemented method in log4j 2.7